# Is it possible to get the position of a device on usb using libusb

Tags: c++, usb, libusb

I have a couple of usb devices wich consist of the device itself and a internal USB hub in order to chain connect more of this devices. Is it somehow possible to get the actual position of one specific device on this usb chain using libusb or anything similar in a c++ program?

Using `lsusb -t` on linux i can get a tree of the bus which looks like this

```
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8152, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 20, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 21, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ftdi_sio, 12M
```

On the mac I can use `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` to get something similar. Can I get it also programmatically using `libusb` ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See libusb_get_port_numbers:

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#gaa4b7b2b50a9ce2aa396b0af2b979544d